# Getting an error when I try to use a variable from my script in my function

Tags: python, list, function, variables

I have a function:

```
def Hanoi(A):

    pegA=['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
```

If I call the function

```
Hanoi(pegA)
```

(I am using Autodesk Maya)

I get this error: name 'pegA' is not defined

I was under the impression that you could use a variable from your script in a function? Can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you define `pegA` before `Hanoi`? Can you show the code preceding that function call?

Comment: As the error message says, you need to define pegA before passing it to Hanoi.

Comment: i don't! i'm guessing that's my problem?!

Comment: From "(I am using Autodesk Maya)" I'm guessing you're not simply running this Python script from the command line, right? Are you invoking it from inside Maya somehow? Also, are you using `A` anywhere inside the function? Maybe you could define the function as accepting no arguments, and then call it with no arguments.

Comment: hi @Kevin yes I am running it inside maya (this is just a snippet of my code) I use A in the code because I use Hanoi again within the function, my script uses recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code:

```
def Hanoi(A):
    pegA=['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
```

You've defined a function `Hanoi`, and when the function is run, a local variable `pegA` is created. When the function returns, `pegA` is destroyed because it's local

Then when you call the function:

```
Hanoi(pegA)
```

There's no `pegA` to pass *into* the function. It'll get created inside, but doesn't exist outside.

---

What you can do is create `pegA` outside the function, and pass it in:

```
def Hanoi(A):
    print A  # pegA was assigned to A when you called the function

pegA=['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
Hanoi(pegA)
```

---

Lastly, as an aside, the general convention is to start functions with lowercase letters, reserving uppercase for class names.

Answer (score 0):

pegA is defined in the function, but you are passing it as an argument to the function. Basically youre trying to call it before it has been defined